# Call file in another

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am making react native quiz app. I and I want to do some pages with questions, but I have question about this. Look: I have one code that checks answers and prints it. I do not want to past that same code to all pages, I want to make one page with code and at another pages just put in this.state all questions. How I can do this?
Please help me, I will be very grateful to you
Code:

```html
// page with code functions that checks and prints all questions - Function.js

// ...

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
         questionData: this.props.questions, 
      progress: 0,
      score: 0
       }
       this.checkAnswer = this.checkAnswer.bind(this);
      this.resetQuiz = this.resetQuiz.bind(this);
  }

  checkAnswer(index) {
    var correct = this.state.questionData[this.state.progress].correct;
    var newScore = 0, newProgress = 0;
    if (correct === index) {
      newScore = this.state.score + 1;
      this.setState({score: newScore});
      newProgress = this.state.progress + 1;
      this.setState({progress: newProgress});
    } else {
      newProgress = this.state.progress + 1;
      this.setState({progress: newProgress});
    }
  }
  resetQuiz() {
    this.setState({score: 0, progress: 0});
  }
  
    render() {
        var questionDatum = this.state.questionData[this.state.progress];
        return (
            <ScrollView>
            <View style={styles.main}>
                  {this.state.questionData.length > this.state.progress ? 
                  (
                  <View>
                    // ...
               </View> 
                  ):(
                   // ...
                  </ScrollView>
        )
    }
}


// page with questions - Main.js

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.questions = [{prompt: "Question 1", answers: ["a","b","c","d"], correct: 2}, {prompt: "Question 2", answers: ["a","b","c","d"], correct: 0}]
       
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to read about stateful and stateless components. What you want to achieve can be done in different ways. You can put your logic code (where you check answers and whatever) in a parent component of all the pages you need (like in `<App>`) and just pass down with properties to the different pages (functional components).

Also a more elegant solutions is to use redux to store your info there and just connect the components you need to the store to retrieve the information.